# External access to web application running in EC2 instance - AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a web application configured and running in a EC2 VM with Windows Server. When I was configuring the instance I created security groups to allow inbound and outbound access: including RDP, HTTP and HTTPS with IP 0.0.0.0/0. 
My ideia is to let it running and access my application from anywhere only using its address (for example: http://ip:port/my-application/index.html) in a browser. However, I can't access it from my local machine since it can't find this address. Testing it inside the EC2 instance works normally.

I understood that once you have the public IP and DNS your machine would be available to access through the Internet and the instance would translate these information to the ones to allow access it, but I still have this issue. 
What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the actual error message? The statement "it can't find this address" needs more context. Are you sure you are using the public IP (or public DNS) instead of the private IP? It sounds like you are doing everything correctly, although you might also need to open the ports in the Windows firewall on the server.

Comment: I used the public IP to access it and the message error is the one when the browser can't find an address. Do I still have to configure the EC2 firewall?

Answer (score 2):

If the instance is not EC2 classic, you need to add Internet Gateway to be able to accessed from internet and add appropriate routes.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html

Comment: Hi, sorry the delay. I followed the article configuring the Internet Gateway (I used the one already created and associated with my instance) but I still have the problem of accessing my app from my local machine. I'm using the elastic IP created from the article but the browser shows the error that the address took too long to answer. Any other tips?

Answer (score 0):

You could try running your server with --host 0.0.0.0 
We had a similar situation with a nodeJs project on an EC2 instance. The application was accessible from browsers only after we added the --host 0.0.0.0 to the package.json

Answer (score 0):

Check your window firewall rules they are stoping you to access your application remotely.